# Memory Usage for Maximum Depth of Binary Tree Solution

Tags: python, binary-tree

Why is there such a big difference in memory usage between these two solutions (in Python) to finding the maximum depth of a binary tree? It looks like the first solution uses a helper function for recursive calls but it's doing the same thing as the second solution. Having trouble understanding this.

~5KB used

```
class Solution(object):
    def maxDepth(self, root):
        """
        :type root: TreeNode
        :rtype: int
        """
        return self.maxDepthH(root)
    
    def maxDepthH(self, root):
        if root == None:
            return 0
        else:
            templ = 1 + self.maxDepthH(root.left)
            tempr = 1 + self.maxDepthH(root.right)
            return max(templ, tempr)
```

~28KB used

```
class Solution(object):
    # depth = 0
    def maxDepth(self, root):
        """
        :type root: TreeNode
        :rtype: int
        """
        if root is None:
            return 0
        
        left = 1 + self.maxDepth(root.left)
        right = 1 + self.maxDepth(root.right)
        
        # depth = max(left, right)
        return max(left, right)
```

Comment: how are you profiling the memory usage?

Comment: This is from a leetcode problem where they list solutions by percentile for memory usage

Comment: you really have to provide a self-contained example. You claim something uses more memory, so you really need to provide us with a reproducible way to confirm that

Comment: I guess, it's better than spoj where your code length and file size not matter. btw you are getting this because of the scope of the variable you use, in the second solution it stays there (in local of function scope) but in the first one it got deleted once it returns the value